# Mongoose update not saved in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing a strange issue with Mongoose Update, and I don't know where to search anymore...

I would like to update a document (I want to update because I need to exclude validation) from a model method. This is my code:

```
module.exports.plugin = function(schema){

    schema.add( { deletedAt : { type : Date, default: null } });

    schema.methods.softDelete = function(done){

        this.update({_id: this._id}, {deletedAt: new Date()}, function(err, num, raw){
            logger.info(err, 'Number Updated: ' + num);
            logger.info(raw);
            done(err, num);
        });
    };
};
```

The function is correctly triggered, this is the output of the logger:

```
Number Updated: 1
(ok=true, n=1, updatedExisting=true)
```

that made me suppose that everything works, but then (checking directly in mongo) the field `deletedAt` has not been updated.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the schema definition look like? Does it have the `deletedAt` property?

Comment: Yes, this a plugin that is attached to more than one schema, but the deletedAt proporty id defined here in the plugin with `schema.add( { deletedAt : { type : Date, default: null } });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the instance version of the [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) method, you don't provide a query conditions parameter as the method already knows to update the current instance.

So your method should look like this instead:

```
schema.methods.softDelete = function(done){

    this.update({$set: {deletedAt: new Date()}}, function(err, num, raw){
        logger.info(err, 'Number Updated: ' + num);
        logger.info(raw);
        done(err, num);
    });
};
```